# React.js fadeIn + delay for each element on render

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, flux

So I using FLUX to manage my react project. Bellow is the code for a component that returns a list of characters.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {isEqual} from 'underscore';
import CharacterListStore from '../stores/CharacterListStore';
import CharacterListActions from '../actions/CharacterListActions';

class CharacterList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = CharacterListStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    CharacterListStore.listen(this.onChange);
    CharacterListActions.getCharacters(this.props.params);
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    CharacterListStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!isEqual(prevProps.params, this.props.params)) {
      CharacterListActions.getCharacters(this.props.params);
    }
  }

  onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }


  render() {
    let charactersList = this.state.characters.map((character, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={character.characterId} className='list-group-item animated fadeIn'>
          <div className='media'>
            <span className='position pull-left'>{index + 1}</span>
            <div className='pull-left thumb-lg'>
              <Link to={'/characters/' + character.characterId}>
                <img className='media-object' src={'http://image.eveonline.com/Character/' + character.characterId + '_128.jpg'} />
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className='media-body'>
              <h4 className='media-heading'>
                <Link to={'/characters/' + character.characterId}>{character.name}</Link>
              </h4>
              <small>Race: <strong>{character.race}</strong></small>
              <br />
              <small>Bloodline: <strong>{character.bloodline}</strong></small>
              <br />
              <small>Wins: <strong>{character.wins}</strong> Losses: <strong>{character.losses}</strong></small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='list-group'>
          {charactersList}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CharacterList;
```

The component gets the data through the Action and updates the store, then renders the html elements based on the state.

---

My question is: Would it be possible for me to implement something that could fade in each item individually with a delay of 500ms for each item on the render?

I've been told **not** to use JQuery in react, so I guess I'm struggling to think in react, any help or advice is appreciated. thank you in advance

Comment: http://mxstbr.blog/2015/07/fade-in-react/ or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fade, help you?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at React's animation documentation - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup

You could use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` or `ReactTransitionGroup` for the animation.

If you want to fade the items in sequentially one by one, you could use css `transition-delay` property.

Alternatively you could control the sequencing by recursively calling a timeout function that will set the component's state, concatenating the next character to state until `this.state.characters.length` === `state.characters.length`
*(Be sure to destroy the timeout function in the case of unmounting the component before all characters have been dealt with)*